# Can I find the hash using a partial hash address in order to look it up at etherscan.io?

Tags: etherscan, addresses, hash

For example **0x0DDF2…e7D19**

How can I find/search for the reminder the address?
The auto complete feature is no longer available at etherscan.io

Comment: Hi! It may be helpful to know where you found the fragment - oftentimes there's a way to expand it.

Comment: There is no way to expand it. It's off a picture. @TheRenaissance

Answer (score 0):

You can play around in dune.com, they have indexed datasets. For example, if you think this is an address that made at least one transaction on the Ethereum mainnet, you can construct a query eg:

1. Create > New query > Raw > ethereum transactions
2. Put in the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ethereum.transactions
WHERE LOWER(CAST("from" AS VARCHAR)) LIKE '0x0DDF2%' AND LOWER(CAST("from" AS VARCHAR)) LIKE '%e7D19'
```

Or play around with the other datasets in there. Also, there's a beta AI query editor/generator in the query field, so it might be helpful too.